# How to align all td in the table in the same row

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, html-table, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo ui treeview. In that I am adding the treeview nodes dynamically, and I am using kendo ui template. I have defined the template like this:

```
  <script id="treetemplate" type="text/kendo-ui-template">


              <table id='treeviewtable'>

      # if (item.categoryName == "Textbox") { #  
        <tr>
        <td>
          <label style="color:red">#=item.label#</label>
        </td>
        <td>
      <label>#=item.val#</label>
        </td>
        # } #

          # if (item.categoryName == "Dropdown") { #            

                  <td>
        <label style="color:red">#=item.label#</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <label>#=item.val#</label>  
         </td>
         # } #

    </table>
    </script>
```

I have defined the treeview like this:

```
       var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                  template: kendo.template($("#treetemplate").html()),
                  dataSource: homogeneous,
                  dataTextField: ["categoryName"],

              }).data("kendoTreeView");

              kendo.init($("#treeview-left"));
```

I have written a ajax and dynamically appending treeview child like this:

```
   var selectedNode = treeview.select();

   if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
        selectedNode = null;
    }

   treeview.append({
      categoryName: json[i].categoryName, label: json[i].label, val: json[i].val
   }, selectedNode);
```

It is working fine. My question is I want to add the controls in a table format with each tr contains two controls. Like I want to display the textbox and dropdown side by side. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One first comment is that the labels of the HTML `table` in the `template` are not correctly balanced... but this will not affect the result.

In KendoUI tree-nodes are HTML unordered list (`ul`) so you have each node content inside an HTML list item (`li`). Knowing this you might understand that using your table, each node is a different table so one item doesn't know about the width of the previous/next one and they will not keep same width.

So, you need to *style* the list elements to `float`. Define the following style:

If you know the width of each of the two columns you might define two CSS styles as:

```
#treeview li.k-item {
    float: left;
}
```

Now, your template might be something like:

```
<script id="treetemplate" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    # if (item.categoryName == "Textbox") { #
    <div><label class="ob-label" style="color:red">#=item.label#</label></div>
    <div><label class="ob-val">#=item.val#</label></div>
    # } #

    # if (item.categoryName == "Dropdown") { #
    <div><label class="ob-label" style="color:green">#=item.label#</label></div>
    <div><label class="ob-val">#=item.val#</label></div>
    # } #
</script>
```

You might see an running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/t6UeG/1/

Depending on what you want to get, you might use [KendoUI Menus](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/menu/index.html)

Comment: nice example. But i want both the datasource items side by side. I mean in the example there are two rows and one column. But i need two columns and one row